# Unable to delete machine image using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a machine image called `client-template`, so that the output of
`gcloud compute machine-images list` is:

```
NAME: client-template
STATUS: READY
```

However, my attempt to delete this image:

```
gcloud compute images delete client-template
```

results in the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.images.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/myproject/global/images/client-template' was not found
```

I see that it is trying to find the image in `global/images/`, whereas when I use this image to create an instance, I have to use `global/machineImages/`. I tried to specify the name along with the path on the command line, but it does not match the regular expression for the names of the images. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/delete) does not seem to provide any hint.

The command is part of an automation script, so I cannot just remove the image using the web interface.

So, how do I fix my command to delete this machine image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image is different, Machine Image is different.

when you try to run a command,

```
gcloud compute images delete client-template
```

It is going to search for client-template in the **Images** to delete it which is not available there because it's a **machine image**, not an image.

So, to delete a machine image, you've to run the following command,

```
gcloud compute machine-images delete client-template
```